# Get the list of files of particular extension using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have files of particular ext (.mtc) in a folder and i would like to count of no of files in the folder Desktop\Foldername of this ext in that folder and run an exe that accepts each of the file as a parameter.

For eg
1. a.mtc
2. abc.mtc
3. xyz.mtc

For each of above file, i want my exe to run using the batch script.

**I also need to ensure that it resets the count back to 0 when i run the batch file again**

Appreciate your response.

Comment: @arkascha the OP specified `batch` in title and [tag:batch-file] for tags. There are no edits to the OP at the time of me writing, so you should have seen it too. What's the problem?

Comment: Do you really want the number of files ? Last 2 answers did not mention it but no comment from your side.

Comment: @Slav So you say "batch" is a MS-Windows term? LOL... I'd say apparently my comment made it clear that this question is about an MS-Windows environment. So all is fine :-)

Comment: Yes Mat, i also need count of no of files in a variable so that i can set max of the files count to run my.exe

Comment: @arkascha Yes, click the [tag:batch-file] tag and read the description. A "batch file" is definitely an "MS-Windows term" in this context. "Batch processing" or simply the word "batch" may have other meanings in other contexts, but it is not ambiguous here, as the OP correctly used it in the title and in the tag. If you want to dispute the apparent ambiguity of the tag, you can take that up to the [meta]. But like you said, all is fine here. Obligatory "LOL".

Comment: @Slav I absolutely have no intention to have this discussed somewhere. That makes no sense. All I pointed out was that it makes sense to specify as clearly as possible in what environment a question is situated to get good and precise answers. In my personal background "batch" is something completely different compared to that explanation you cite, and I, just like everyone else here, obviously invest only fractions of a second to glance over the tags to decide if a question is of interest/something one can contribute to. So an additional tag "Windows" would have made things clearer. Not more.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

pushd "path to desktop"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.mtc') do (your.exe "%%~nxa")
popd
```

Comment: Thanks but i am looking to pass the filename as parameter to batch file so that i can run my exe with that parameter for all the files. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "ext=%~1"
pushd "%userprofile%\desktop\folder"
for %%a in (*.%ext%) do (
    your.exe "%%~nxa"
)
popd
```

Matt Williamson's answer with the new added requirements